# What is a sharp bound on the difference between $f$ and its linear approximation on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

So I have the following problem. Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [-1,1]$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq \lvert x - y \rvert$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$. An example of such a function is drawn in Figure 1.

[image]

Now I am interested in the maximal distance between function $f$ and a piecewise linear function $h$. I will focus on the interval $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ where $h$ is simply a linear approximation of $f$. Now I want to know what the maximal distance between function $f$ and the linear line is (see Figure 2). I know that this maximal distance is located at $c$, where the tangent line of the function $f$ is equal to the linear line.

[image]

Now the smoothness constraint on the top should give me some information on how large the difference, $\ell$, can be. However, I have not been able to find a tight bound. I think it should be something like,
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\lvert f(x) - h(x)\rvert < \frac{1}{2(b-a)}
\end{align}

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if something about the problem is unclear.

Comment: That inequality can't be right, because you can multiply $f$ (and thus $h$) by a large constant to inflate the left-hand side without affecting the right-hand side. A correct inequality will involve $f'(x)$, as in the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin for your comment. Note though that $\lvert f'(x)\rvert = \lvert\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \rvert \leq 1$ by the constraint on the top of the page. Then the right-hand side can be such that it does not involve $f'(x)$ explicitly right?